# In perl Script how to use 'use' and 'GO' sql statement ? i have one perl script but i am getting syntax error

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a database and USE statement then create a table in the same database.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI; 
my $host = 'idcqeam726.amdom281.lab'; 
my $database = 'master'; 
my $user = 'sa'; 
my $auth = 'Control123'; 
# DBD::ADO 
$dsn = "Provider=sqloledb;Trusted Connection=yes;"; 
$dsn .= "Server=$host;Database=$database"; 
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ADO:$dsn",  $user,  $auth,  { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1}) || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
$dbh->do("CREATE DATABASE [LowBCHR] ");
$dbh->do("ALTER DATABASE [LowBCHR] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE ");
$dbh->do("USE LowBCHR;
CREATE TABLE TestTable(RowID BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY ,JoinVal BIGINT DEFAULT ( 0 ) NOT NULL ,DateChange DATETIME2 DEFAULT ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) NOT NULL ,DataCol NCHAR ( 500 ) DEFAULT ( 'BCHR' ));
qq{BEGIN TRANSACTION DECLARE \@i INT = 1 WHILE \@i <= 30000 BEGIN INSERT INTO TestTable ( JoinVal )VALUES ( \@i % 10 )SET \@i = \@i + 1 END};");
```

I am getting error like:

```
DBD::ADO::db do failed: Can't Execute 'USE LowBCHR;
Description : Syntax error or access violation
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of use, just prepend the DB name to your SQL statement `dbname.tablename` (also I believe you were doing two commands there, so check the parsing):

```
$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE LowBCHR.TestTable(RowID BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY
    KEY ,JoinVal BIGINT DEFAULT ( 0 ) NOT NULL ,DateChange DATETIME2
    DEFAULT ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) NOT NULL ,DataCol NCHAR ( 500 ) DEFAULT
   ( 'BCHR' )");

$dbh->do("BEGIN TRANSACTION DECLARE \@i INT = 1 WHILE \@i <= 30000
    BEGIN INSERT INTO LowBCHR.TestTable ( JoinVal )VALUES ( \@i % 10 )SET
    \@i = \@i + 1 END");
```